# Time series - ARIMA Model gives bad result of prediction

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, arima

I don't understand why I get poor prediction results with ARIMA Model
Here is my program and my results:

for the dataset I am using a file (which represents CPU traces of one VM)that contains 288 values each value represents the CPU utilization  every 5 min during 24h (I got it from the PlanetLab datset of cloudsim)

[image]

graph of 288 values

[image]

result:
stationnarity test

[image]

PACF and ACF :

[image]

Model fit :

[image]

I tried the Out-Of-Time Cross-Validation method and i got the same poor prediction

---

Another model with poor prediction

[image]

stationarity test :

[image]

PACF:

[image]

ACF:

[image]

[image]

prediction :

[image]

[image]

you will notice that the max value of the prediction is a little over 40 while in the real series it exceeds 160

Comment: Based on your plots, I would recommend you start by examining your data on a log-scale (i.e., model $\log y$ instead of $y$).  From your ACF and PACF (which show no autocorrelation or partial autocorrelation on the regular scale) it seems to me that you might have something similar to a set of IID lognormal values.  Bear in mind that if values are independent, or close to it, your forecast will be roughly constant once you have a reasonable amount of data --- consequently, the forecast results you get are not all that surprising or problematic.

Comment: See also [some other threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arima+flat+forecast) where users are suspicious of flat forecasts that turn out to be potentially close to optimal.